# Add locations individually in map view to existing table rows?

Tags: carto, geocoding

I have a table in which many records have long/lat info, but many others do not.  In other words the locations for those records are currently unknown.  Therefore there are many records that are visible in table view, but not in map view.  This is not an error, it is just the current state of my database.

I would like to be able to add the locations manually, case by case, as they become known. I was hoping there was a way to do that. I know you can add new records via the map view and table view. And you can edit existing records in the table view. I am wondering if you can edit an existing record in the map view by clicking on the map to indicate that location. The long and lat where clicked would populate the table.

If not, through the existing UI, what would be the best way to implement such functionality?

Comment: Could you find the locations easily ? I would locate the lat/long for the missing cells and re-populatate the CSV, personally.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  No, there are too many and in any case I want users to be able to add them manually on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is missing here would be the possibility to click on the table on an empty geometry, and where you have the possibility to enter the latitude and longitude manually, you can actually click on "Map" and get to choose the location directly on a contextual map.

I think moving to the map itself will be confusing, but if a little box with a map (with the visualization already on the map) would get displayed, I think ti could be effective.

What you think?

Comment: Let's see: In table view, you click on an empty (null) geometry cell and it triggers a pop-up visualization/map, on which you can click; the click returns the long/lat of where you clicked and populates the table.  That would be great-- so this would be custom functionality.  How would it be developed?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, couple things...

1. In the georeference by column interface, the order of entry is Longitude then Latitude, not the other way around. That is a common mistake, so ensure you are doing that.
2. If you run, "SELECT count(*) WHERE the_geom IS NULL" in the SQL menu, you can see how many are missing geometries. If it is much lower than your row count, maybe see #1 or make sure you are looking in the right place

Comment: Thanks.  No the missing info is missing-- it was never there.  Some records had the long/lat info but some did not.  I am looking for the functionality to add the " missing" location info manually on the map for existing rows.

Answer (score 0):

Kenny,

CartoDb allows for rapid display of your Lat/Lon data once you upload the CSV file, but the points with missing Lat/Lon can still be displayed after you use the Geocoder to find their place on the map. (All of this is possible *only* if you have **another column in your CSV with a placename or address field**.)

This is slightly advanced functionality: in the column display of your CSV file inside CartoDb there is a down-arrow next to each of your text fields. (Hopefully one of your fields represents something like a place name or an address, as these are the most common geocoding sources to generate positions (Lat/Lon) from.)  Pull down that arrow on the field header for your address text field and choose "Create an Address Column..."

Toggling this column header instructs CartoDb to geocode the address column and to create Lat/Lon positions for these records.

So, in order to get all your points mapped, you need to have at least four columns in your CSV: Name, Lat, Lon, Address and either the Lat/Lon or Address fields must be filled in before you upload.

Hope this helps,

Jason S., GISP  aka JasonInVegas

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I guess maybe I should edit my original question for clarity.  I actually want to be able to add the locations manually, case by case.  I was hoping there was a way to do that.  You can add new records via the map view and table view.  and edit existing records in the table view.  I am wondering if you can edit an existing record in the map view by clicking on the map to indicate that location.  The long and lat would populate the table.